# $_POST is not being set correctly

Tags: php, post

**FRONT END CODE**

```
    <form action="search.php" method="POST">

    <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-inset="true" data-filter-       reveal="true"  data-filter-placeholder="Search by Ingredients">

                    <!-- 1-10 -->
                   <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="search" id="ing1" class="custom" value="Passion Fruit"/>
                        <label for="ing1">Passion Fruit</label>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="search" id="ing2" class="custom" value="Banana"/>
                        <label for="ing2">Banana</label>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="search" id="ing3" class="custom" value="Mango"/>
                        <label for="ing3">Mango</label>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="search" id="ing4" class="custom" value="Orange Juice"/>
                        <label for="ing4">Orange Juice</label>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="search" id="ing5" class="custom" value="Ice"/>
                        <label for="ing5">Ice</label>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="search" id="ing6" class="custom" value="Sausages"/>
                        <label for="ing6">Sausages</label>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="search" id="ing7" class="custom" value="Bacon"/>
                        <label for="ing7">Bacon</label>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="search" id="ing8" class="custom" value="Eggs"/>
                        <label for="ing8">Eggs</label>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="search" id="ing9" class="custom" value="Beans"/>
                        <label for="ing9">Beans</label>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="search" id="ing10" class="custom" value="Milk"/>
                        <label for="ing10">Milk</label>
                    </li>

            </ul>

    <br />
    <input type="submit" action="search.php" value="Search For Recipes">
    </form>
```

**PHP CODE**

```
     if (isset($_POST['search'])) {

     $choices = $_POST["search"];
     $count = count($choices);

     echo "<h1>" . $count . "</h1>";
     echo "<h1>" . $choices . "</h1>";

     }
```

nothing is being returned when i check some boxes so this suggests to me the checkbox is not being picked up correctly :S HELPP!!!! i am making a web app searchable list hence the cod for this

Answer (score 4):

checkboxes are not radiobuttons. Their names must be different otherwise you're returning only the last one!

If you want to retrieve them all, you have to change every checkbox name from `search` to `search[]`. This way, you'll be able to retrieve them all into a single array, located into `$_REQUEST['search']` (*)

If, instead, you want to have only one possible selection, change the inputs type from checkbox to radiobutton and keep the current name.

(*) `$_REQUEST` is a superglobal variable which contains the same values you'll find in `$_POST` or `$_GET`. It's the best choice usually to write flexible scripts (you may have to change the form's method and with `$_REQUEST` you won't have to rewrite the whole PHP script in the back end.

Comment: You can also name the elements.

E.g. "search[1]" allowing you to more easily pull out a value relating to a specific id, etc...

Comment: sure. I often do that too in more complex forms. I think that's better to start with the basics for now and for this problem, at least. Thanks for the heads up. :)

Comment: I don't think OP wants only one selection, then there are no reason for counting number of choices. +1 for issuing the problem and explaining it well.

Comment: Comment was aimed more as additional info for the OP on top of this answer. Didn't think it warranted it's own answer :).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `name="search"` you could use `name="search[]"`, that way, when `$_POST` is populated in PHP, it creates an array of values. What you have now just takes one of the elements, because all of their names are the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is get your results in an array because I can see you are trying to execute :

```
$choices = $_POST["search"];
$count = count($choices);
```

If you want this to work, you'll have to change the `name` attribute for your input elements.
Try giving them a name in this format:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="ing1" name="search[]" .../>
<input type="checkbox" id="ing2" name="search[]" .../>
<input type="checkbox" id="ing3" name="search[]" .../>
```

I'm fairly sure that the issues you are facing are because multiple elements share the same name so their values are being overridden.

---

If you'd like your results to be in an associative array that will let you access each element individually and by name, you could pace the value of the id attribute inside the name attribute as well - like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="ing1" name="search[ing1]" .../>
<input type="checkbox" id="ing2" name="search[ing2]" .../>
<input type="checkbox" id="ing3" name="search[ing3]" .../>
```

Now you'll be able to access the elements like this:

```
$_POST["search"]['ing1']
$_POST["search"]['ing2']
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to name all your checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="search[]" ...
```

into the php

```
if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
    print_r($_POST['search']);die();
}
```

Comment: Just to make sure he gets the structure of the variable.

Comment: die() only makes sure that the PHP stops executing. But that would happen anyway in OP's case?

Comment: It stop executing so the developer can see the structure of the variable and then can see how to access the values and remove it to implement the rest properly, it is there just for debugging purpose.

Answer (score 0):

change the name of the checkbox "search" with "search[]" also remove the action attribute from submit button.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `name="search"` you need to write `name="search[]"`, so that PHP can fetch the values from the Array.

index.php

```
<form action="search.php" method="POST">

    <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-inset="true" data-filter-       reveal="true"  data-filter-placeholder="Search by Ingredients">

                    <!-- 1-10 -->
                   <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="search[]" id="ing1" class="custom" value="Passion Fruit"/>
                        <label for="ing1">Passion Fruit</label>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="search[]" id="ing2" class="custom" value="Banana"/>
                        <label for="ing2">Banana</label>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="search[]" id="ing3" class="custom" value="Mango"/>
                        <label for="ing3">Mango</label>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="search[]" id="ing4" class="custom" value="Orange Juice"/>
                        <label for="ing4">Orange Juice</label>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="search[]" id="ing5" class="custom" value="Ice"/>
                        <label for="ing5">Ice</label>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="search[]" id="ing6" class="custom" value="Sausages"/>
                        <label for="ing6">Sausages</label>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="search[]" id="ing7" class="custom" value="Bacon"/>
                        <label for="ing7">Bacon</label>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="search[]" id="ing8" class="custom" value="Eggs"/>
                        <label for="ing8">Eggs</label>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="search[]" id="ing9" class="custom" value="Beans"/>
                        <label for="ing9">Beans</label>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="search[]" id="ing10" class="custom" value="Milk"/>
                        <label for="ing10">Milk</label>
                    </li>

            </ul>

    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Search For Recipes">
    </form>
```

search.php

```
if (isset($_POST['search'])) {

 $choices = "";
 $count   = count($_POST["search"]);

 for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++) {

     $choices .= $_POST["search"][$i] . " ";
 }


 echo "<h1>" . $count . "</h1>";
 echo "<h1>" . $choices . "</h1>";

 }
```

Comment: Tryed this and it returns nothing. using local host via xammp

Comment: @user2346125 please double check the code and run it again. It's running good in my localhost...

Answer (score 0):

Answers has been given to change the name of element from search to search[] and that is of course correct, but take a look at your php-code as well:

```
 if (isset($_POST['search'])) {

 $choices = $_POST["search"];
 $count = count($choices);

 echo "<h1>" . $count . "</h1>";
 echo "<h1>" . $choices . "</h1>";

 }
```

I believe what you want is list the items being selected, then you could iterate the choices in a foreach-loop like this: Note that I'm using H2 instead of H1 because using several H1's on a html-page would not validate correctly. (Of course you could a `span` or something else, it's just an example)

```
 if (isset($_POST['search'])) {

 $choices = $_POST["search"];
 $count = count($choices);

 echo "<h1>" . $count . "</h1>";

 foreach($choices as $choice) {
  echo "<h2>" . $choice . "</h2>";
 }

 }
```

Instead of making checkboxes like you do I would put all item into an array and then do an iteratation to create the `<li>`-tags with its contents. *(because it's more flexible and you don't have to rewrite same thing over and over again)*

The code would look something like this:

```
<form action="search.php" method="POST">
<ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-inset="true" data-filter-       reveal="true"  data-filter-placeholder="Search by Ingredients">

<!-- 1-10 -->                   
<?php
$ingredientsArray = array('Passion Fruit', 'Banana', 'Mango', 'Orange Juice', 'Ice', 'Sausages', 'Bacon', 'Eggs', 'Beans', 'Milk');

$cnt = 0;
foreach($ingredientsArray as $ingredient) {
    $cnt++;
    echo '<li>';
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="search[]" id="ing' . $cnt . '" class="custom" value="' . $ingredient. '"/>';
    echo '<label for="ing' . $cnt . '">' . $ingredient. '</label>';
    echo '</li>';
}
?>
</ul>

<br />
<input type="submit" value="Search For Recipes">
</form>
```

Comment: why `action="search.php"` attribute in submit button?

Comment: @6339 - no of course, that's not necessary. Thanks! (I just copied that part of the html from OP) I've deleted that part.